# Apache 2.4.20 build errors on windows 7 (64 bit OS)

Tags: c, apache, visual-studio-2010

From last few days am trying to build apache version 2.4.20 source code with visual studio 2010 on windows 7 64 bit OS but am getting following errors.
I compiled many times, while compiling am getting different link errors but these are the common errors for every build.

- error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\httpd-2.4.20\support\Debug\cl.read.1.tlog' because it is being used by another process.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets
- error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: Path(C:\httpd-2.4.20\modules\loggers\Debug\link-cvtres.read.1.tlog). The file exists.

Both errors are coming for different paths(C:\httpd-2.4.20\modules\aaa\Debug\cl.read.1.tlog) etc.

- error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\ide\devenv.COM"' : return code '0x1'  C:\httpd-2.4.20\NMAKE
- error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'    C:\httpd-2.4.20\NMAKE

I don't know why these errors are coming could you please help me to get out from these errors.
Thanks.

Comment: 1) kill any all currently executing `apache` instances.  2) empty the `/tmp` and `/temp` folders 3) update to latest `.net` version 4) google any other error messages for further details

Comment: I followed your steps but again same errors are occurring. Is their any alternate solution for this issue? or if you already build apache for windows could you please share build steps

Comment: regarding this: `error MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\httpd-2.4.20\support\Debug\cl.read.1.tlog' because it is being used by another process. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets`  1) `cl.exe` is the actual compiler, which it cannot find.  2) some log is being used, reboot or kill the application using that file to fix 3)

Comment: one possible suggestion: do not multithread the compile/link processing.  It will take longer, but should give the compile/link a much better chance of completing successfully.